# Taking all the values from a dropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

If a website has a dropDownList, is it possible to extract all the values along with their ID using c#?

Thanks

As in:

```
<select name='dropDownList'  >
<option value='0'>Watever</option>
<option value="1">Watever</option>
<option value="2">Watever</option>
<option value="3">Watever</option>
<option value="4">Watever</option>
```

I want to extract all the "value" as well as their corresponsing text.

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) allows web pages to be parsed easily.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?  Is this your website or someone else's site?

Comment: Its a third party site. Why would I do this on my own site?

Comment: You should be using HtmlAgilityPack for this.  There are numerous examples to choose from, on this site and others.  You will have to download the HTML from the site and parse it with HtmlAgilityPack.  Please download it and give it a try.  When you reach another stopping point, please ask a specific question regarding your problem.

Comment: So it isnt possible to access the page using a WebBrowser and interact programmatically with the select element? I did this once in ASP.NET, but that had classes that represent each html element. I don't know if this can be done in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ASP.NET site and add the dropdown list as element you can easily get/set the properties. If it´s not your site and you use a client to get to the html code you have to parse it. For html the HtmlAgilityPack is the best solution but you can also try to use regex if the query isn´t to complex.

Answer (score 1):

I have already scrapped many sites, but there is no hard and fast rule for it.

I always use my own logic and easiest way is the sub string.

1. Take entire page HTML as a string
2. use substring to get all the option
3. split the option to do the for loop
4. do the for loop
5. in every loop subtract you value and text

I am not saying that there is no better way but hardly you will get any.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Did it using HTMLAgilityPack, very fast.